# How to solve the following an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x,y,z$ be a given point in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

How to solve $(x'(t),y'(t),z'(t))=(x(x+y+z), y(x+y+z),z(x+y+z))$?

Comment: Hint: Consider $$(x+y+z)' = x'+y'+z' = (x+y+z)^2$$

Comment: @johannesvalks Great hint.

Comment: I have tried $(x+y+z)'=(x+y+z)^2$. But, this only tells us that $x(t)+y(t)+z(t)=-\frac{1}{t+C}$.

Comment: You can use this information in the original vector of ODEs to solve for $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Comment: Aha, you mean, now the equation becomes $(x'(t),y'(t),z'(t))=(-\frac{x}{t+c},-\frac{y}{t+c},-\frac{z}{t+c})$. I see. However, I need to divide both sides by $x$, $y$, or $z$ respectively. It worries me because $x$, $y$, $z$ might vanish

Comment: @user156937, yes, so you get

$$
x' = -\frac{x}{c+t}, y' = -\frac{y}{c+t}, z' = -\frac{z}{c+t}.
$$